# Where are LEGO parts made?

Tags: manufacturing, lego-group

Are all LEGO parts made in a single factory, or are there multiple factories? Where abouts is it/are they? If there are several, are there different factories for different pieces/sets, or do all factories produce all parts?

Comment: You mean, it's not mined?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

LEGO moulds bricks in the following plants: Billund in Denmark, Nyíregyháza in Hungary and Monterrey in Mexico.

In addition, it has another facility in Kladno, Czech Republic, that handles painting and packaging for some of the bricks produced in Denmark and Hungary.

The headquarters in Denmark is still where the most of R&D and product development happens.

Comment: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/49/are-lego-minifigs-arms-supposed-to-come-off/162#162 says there is also a factory in China for particular things, so this answer is not the whole story, or that answer is wrong...

Comment: Magnets, pens, watches and such have been made in China. These parts are sometimes different plastics from the rest of the line.  Collectible minifigs  also say Made in China.

Comment: Lego has many products besides building sets, including but not limited to bags, pens, costumes, cups etc. The actual building sets are produced as Mikl answers.

Comment: The collectible minifigs are made in China, I believe.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are the rip-off-company ones. If the figure design is shiny, then it's most likely a fake. And you should also look for the Lego logo.

Answer (score 3):

The National Geographic Channel has a series called Ultimate Factories. As it happens, the episode that aired tonight was all about the [LEGO factory in Billund](http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/channel/ultimate-factories/lego-pictures/). The show also looks at the LEGO manufacturing process, product development, and distribution network. If you want to know more about where and how LEGO parts are made, you couldn't do much better than to watch this episode. I'm sure they'll show it again sometime soon -- check you local TV listings.

Answer (score -2):

LEGO is made and has been made in a number of Countries. Denmark, Hungary, Switzerland, Sweden, Austria, Poland, Indonesia, Italy, Germany, Czech Republic, China and Mexico :)